# Появляется Exception в методе db.SaveChange()

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

При использование EF 6.4.4.0 на .Net Framework 4.6.2 появляется исключение при сохранение контекста:
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Все сделано как нужно, есть блок c полной обработкой исключения, где указана ошибка валидации.

```
try {} catch(System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex) {}
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, что проблема в валидации данных, но парадокс в том, что когда я использую метод db.SaveChange() для сохранения 1000 сущностей все отрабатывает как нужно, но как только я сохраняю 1000000 сущностей появляется исключение о валидации.
Я так понимаю, что в EF есть ограничение на обработку сущностей в контексте, если так, то подскажите где это указано и как с этим работать.

Работаю с базой данных Mysql 8.0 на PHP7.3 c InnoDB.

Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Comment: Есть хороший ответ по производительности сохранения контекста https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930982/when-should-i-call-savechanges-when-creating-1000s-of-entity-framework-object, но еще интересует ограничение по максимальному объему.

Answer (score 0):

Методам тестирования было выяснено:

1. Максимальный потолок, когда рушится контекст 2Гб RAM при этом процессор начинается грузится на 4-6% больше от номинального режима.
2. Наилучшая производительность достигнута при сохранение (обновление) 1000 записей с размером 1 записи ~500 байт, при этом после каждой итерации создается новый контекст.